# What is the name of this type of problem

Tags: programming-languages

I've seen the Wikipedia page about it a while ago - but I can't find it now.
The problem is something like:

- Mary lives next to Jane
- Rob has a green door
- Mike likes dogs
- Jeff likes cats and can't live next to Mike
- Steve lives across from Rob and Jane

Who lives next door to Jeff?

It's a really old puzzle (I think World War 1) published in a newspaper and possibly to do with Camel Cigarettes advertising at some point.

the Wiki page discussed various solutions using different software languages, as some families of languages are better suited to these types of solutions

Comment: It is often called a "Smith, Jones, Robinson" puzzle, because the first widely published puzzled used those names for the engineer, conductor and passenger on a train. In general, they are called logic puzzle.s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Constraint Satisfaction Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem). This problem is also a Zebra Puzzle. A kind of Logic Puzzle.

You can find solutions in multiple languages in [Rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zebra_puzzle).

*The rest of this answer is a description of how I figured that out.*

---

The problem in the question reminded me of a "riddle" from a TED-Ed video. I found the [TED-Ed video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rDVz_Fb6HQ) searching in the TED-Ed youtube channel for "riddle thief", which gave me the name "[Einstein's riddle](https://udel.edu/~os/riddle.html)".

Looking for "Einstein's riddle" in Wikipedia, leaded me to the article [Zebra Puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_Puzzle). The article says:

> The puzzle is often called Einstein's Puzzle or Einstein's Riddle because it is said to have been invented by Albert Einstein as a boy; it is also sometimes attributed to Lewis Carroll. However, there is no known evidence for Einstein's or Carroll's authorship and the Life International version of the puzzle mentions brands of cigarette, such as Kools, that did not exist during Carroll's lifetime or Einstein's boyhood.

Althought there are no code examples in the article.

There are some interesting links, among which a couple papers talk about [Constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming):

- [Capturing Contraint Programming Experience: A Case-Based Approach](http://www.cs.ucc.ie/~dgb/papers/Little-Et-Al-2002.pdf)
- [Hybrid Algorithms For The Constraint Satisfaction Problem](http://cse.unl.edu/~choueiry/Documents/Hybrid-Prosser.pdf)

The name "Constraint Satisfaction Problem" which I'm giving you comes from that last paper. The name "Zebra Puzzle" and the fact that it is a "Logic Puzzle" come from Wikipedia.

*I also found the the Rosetta Code link in the Wikipedia article.*

Answer (score 1):

Think this might be Constraint Programming

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming